# Writing a generic function for "find and replace" in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I need to write a generic function for "find and replace in R". How can I write a function that takes the following inputs

- A CSV file (or data frame)
- A string to find, for example "name@email.com"
- A string the replace the found string with, for example "medium"

and rewrites the CSV file/data frame so that all the found strings are replaced with the replacement string?

Comment: what have you tried? is it the exact string or a partial match? e.g. do I replace "the email is name@email.com" with "the email is medium"?  Do you have to do this in R?  the command line tool `sed` is the best thing I can think of for doing what you're asking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a quick function to do the job:

```
library(stringr)

replace_all <- function(df, pattern, replacement) {
  char <- vapply(df, function(x) is.factor(x) || is.character(x), logical(1))
  df[char] <- lapply(df[char], str_replace_all, pattern, replacement)  
  df
}

replace_all(iris, "setosa", "barbosa")
```

Basically, it identifies all the variables in the data frame that are characters or factors, and then applies `str_replace_all` to each column.  Pattern should be a regular expression, but if you want to match a fixed string, you can do (e.g.)

```
replace_all(iris, fixed("setosa"), "barbosa")
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution below will work for "exact" matches:

```
dat <- data.frame(a=letters[1:10], y=letters[10:1]) 
apply(dat, 2, function(v, foo, bar) {v[v==foo]=bar;return(v)}, foo='a', bar='baz')
```

However, this won't replace strings that contain a 1.  It will also have many edge cases that won't work the way you might expect.

As I mentioned in my comment, the command line tool `sed` is ideally suited for this kind of operation.